SPARK SQL : MUST AGGREGATE CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY
I'm getting error as "correlated scalar subqueries must be aggregated to return at most one row."
Nvl(select addr_cntry_cd from (add_cntry_cd, risk, row_number() over partition by add_cntry_cd order by risk desc) as rn from country where derived_addr in (orig, benef, send) ) sub where sub.rn = 1) , 'Not Found') Orig_country 

Here if I do max(addr_cntry_cd) to get just 1 row it gives error as "accessing outer query column is not allowed in this locationfilter"
Any help is appreciated
Running it in azure databricks in spark sql using %sql while running ht code.
Expecting it shouldn't give error while running in adb.

Hi - please update your question with complete SQL statement for each of things you’ve tried - and format them both as code to make them easy to read

Although you really need to put a formatted full SQL statement to get exact help the error message is pretty clear.  You can use max/min/first/last etc. to select a single row from your sub query (I assume "sub").
Alternatively if you really want multiple rows then you must use a full blown join.
